# XPages and unresponsive button after first click

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage with some filters and a button to generate an Excel spreadsheet. It works great.

However, I find that after I run a report, if I change the filter values and attempt to run a new report, the button is unresponsive. I have to click out of the Report tab and come back to the page in order for the button to work.

I seem to remember someone (perhaps, Paul Calhoun) posting a little client side script to solve this issue (sleep function?) but I can't find it.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding XSP.allowSubmit() in onComplete of the eventHandler, or in SSJS on 8.5.3+ view.postScript("XSP.allowSubmit()")

Comment: Thanks Paul. Adding XSP.allowSubmit() in onComplete of the eventHandler does allow me to now change the filters and run a new report. However, it has a side effect that is problematic. I have a keyword field that hides/displays fields in a panel (containing the filter keys) based on the report selection. Once I add the XSP.allowSubmit(), that stops working. Changing a report type, no longer hides/displays the correct filters. My guess is that it somehow turns off the partial refresh?

Comment: Update: This line from Paul Calhoun works: setTimeout(function() { XSP.allowSubmit() }, 1000); It is set in in the client side script event for the button.

Comment: Thank you to both Paul Calhoun and Paul Withers for helping me resolve this!